# No Material Widget Found, try creating a material widget

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I am trying to create a music player and I stared the code for navigation bar and some other customizations. but when I run the app it says

"TabBar widgets require a Material widget ancestor, To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
TabBar"

I am new to flutter so I don't know much please help.

```
import 'package:envymusic/views/home.dart';
import 'package:envymusic/views/library.dart';
import 'package:envymusic/views/account.dart';
import 'package:envymusic/views/explore.dart';

class Tabbar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tabbar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tabbar> createState() => _TabbarState();
}

class _TabbarState extends State<Tabbar> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedTab,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedTab = index;
            });
          },
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: "Home",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
              label: "Explore",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_music),
              label: "Library",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: "Account",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            renderView(
              0,
              const HomeView(),
            ),
            renderView(
              1,
              const ExploreView(),
            ),
            renderView(
              2,
              const LibraryView(),
            ),
            renderView(
              3,
              const AccountView(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget renderView(int tabIndex, Widget view) {
    return IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: _selectedTab != tabIndex,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: _selectedTab == tabIndex ? 1 : 0,
        child: view,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap your Tabbar widget with Material widget.
e.g:

```
Material(
   child: Tabbar(),
),
```